# Cannot use values from other packages

Tags: android, package

Is it possible to access or use methods from different packages (or package libraries) in an Android project?

Comment: you can use methods by making an import to that package and then calling the appropriate method.

Comment: and how would i edit values of variables in other packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import other packages, in order to change values you should define set-functions within the package you are going to import.

e.g

```
public void setString (String sNew) // in case its a string
{
   YOURVALUE = sNew;        // YOURVALUE should be the value you want to change   
}
```

in order to get the value you should use a get-function

```
public String getString ()     
{
   return YOURVALUE;
}
```

just change the type to the one you need.

after that you are able to call these functions like :

```
PACKAGENAME.setString("This is the new Value");
System.out.println(PACKAGENAME.getString());
```